# Built-in ring-counter in c++

Tags: c++

I need a ring-counter that counts from zero to n and resets to 0 again when n is reached. Now I know how to implement that myself, using the modulo operator. But is there a built-in or an std datatype for this?

Comment: boost offers a circular buffer, but it is probably an overkill. Modulo is probably the best option. If you really want a datatype, you can always build your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mod operator is fundamental to C++ and other languages. This is definitely the best operator to use. There aren't any built-in types in C++ that I can think of that support this type of operation, simply because of how easy the mod operator is to use,

```
++count %= n;
```

For example, This simple piece of code increments and mods a number in one line.

As the comment above says, if you really need a type in C++ you can just make it yourself.

Comment: Sorry, must have been a typo.

Comment: Fair enough :) -